# Convert MAUI ImageSource to png

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I'm rendering a signature on the native canvas for Android, iOS, and windows separately. Now, I need to save this locally, so I have converted the view to stream image source format. But I'm not sure how to convert to PNG and save it locally?.

Comment: You need to post the relevant code.  Generally, if you want an image file, you would use the same source that was originally used to create the ImageSource, not the ImageSource itself

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dependency Injection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ri5nJsapOI) to deal with it, implement the interface on the  platform you want.

For example, I did a test on android:

The interface:

```
      public interface MyService
        {
            public  void Convert( string filename, ImageSource img);
        }
    }
```

The implemention:

```
 public class AndroidService : MyService
    {
        public async void Convert(string filename, ImageSource img)
        {
            System.IO.Stream outputStream = null;

            var handler = new FileImageSourceHandler(); 
            Bitmap pic = await handler.LoadImageAsync(img, Android.App.Application.Context);
          
          
            var savedImageFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), filename);
            bool success = false;
            using (outputStream = new System.IO.FileStream(savedImageFilename, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower() == ".png")
                {
                    success = await pic.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, outputStream);
                }
                else
                    success = await pic.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, outputStream);
            }
        }
    }
```